# How to clean redis cache through java program?

Tags: spring-boot, jedis, lettuce, redis-cache

I have spring boot project. I am using redis as cache manager. I want to clear redis cache with java program. I want to call one api and it will clear my cache.

I already know about redis-cli flushdb command.

I am not expecting command line code. Redis cache server can be on any machine.

Answer (score 3):

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis(getHost(), getPort());
jedis.connect();
jedis.flushAll();
jedis.disconnect();
```